# Get data from pytorch's engine evaluate

Tags: python, pytorch, evaluate

Following [this example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html), I got to use the `evaluate` function from [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/references/detection/engine.py). Which returns a `CocoEvaluator` instance.

This function prints this:

```
IoU metric: bbox
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get all the metrics as variables, something like:

```
metrics = evaluate(*args)
print(metrics.boxes.AP.iou05) # prints 0.000 for this case
```

Thank you